# how i can convert number into Indian number system word?

Tags: php

i want to convert number in Indian number system. instead of of **one million** we want **ten lakhs**.
so is there any way to to do so. below is my code to do modification or if there is any other way to do it's than also let me know.

thanks

```
    $number = '1000500';
    
    $locale = 'en_IN';
    $fmt = numfmt_create($locale, NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
    $in_words = numfmt_format($fmt, $number);
    print_r($in_words);
```

**Current output :**

One Million One Hundred Eighty Thousand Five Hundred Ninety

**Expected Output :**

Ten lakhs One Hundred Eighty Thousand Five Hundred Ninety

Comment: have you installed the `intl` php module? This module is required in order to make the `numfmt` functions to work. You can change this in your `php.ini`

Comment: There is no built-in way since Locale does not encode for how numbers are spelled out by default.  Take a look at [this php issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75305) and [the suggested solution](https://3v4l.org/NY4RE) that uses a [RuleBasedNumberFormatter](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/numbers/rbnf.html#rulebasednumberformat)

Comment: Just replace the One Million to Ten Lakhs, Just define a function and write down the logic on it.

Comment: Please also post the current code for your expenses. The value 1000500 never results in such expenses.